# Fill a Select field with a Json call back using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a pretty new in this area (one mounth) and I'm developing application with angularJs, I'm getting back Json requisition with a list, I have to put the name (`{{empresa.name }}`) when the  user select I get the ID(`{{empresa.IdEmpresa}}`).

I want use ng-repeat for that, something like (`ng-repeat="empresa in empresas"`).

I'm getting the Json with the list from the JavaController,  my Entity is named Empresa, I declare a empty object on angular Like that ( `$scope.empresas = {}`) and give the callback to this emprty object, right?!

My select field is like that

```
     <label>Empresa</label>
<select class="form-control">
 <option value="{{empresa.EmpresaId}}">{{empresa.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

how do I use repeat in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your JSON data look like this

```
$scope.empresas = [
  { EmpresaId: 1, name: 'one' },
  { EmpresaId: 2, name: 'two' },
  { EmpresaId: 3, name: 'three' }
]
```

Apart from using `ng-repeat` on `<options>`, you can also utilise `ng-options`

```
<select ng-options="e.EmpresaId as e.name for e in empresas" ng-model="???"></select>
```

Comment: I'll see the usage of ng-option on documentation of AngularJs , i never see that directive .
I forget that the the model that will receive that selection is ng-model="colaborador.empresa".  
So will be something like that :
<select ng-options="e.EmpresaId as e.name for e in empresas" ng-model="colaborador.empresa">{{empresa.name}}</select>  or I dont need the {{empresa.name}}?

Comment: Take away the `{{empresa.name}}` will do

Comment: My Json its something like that, but have more atributes that I'll not use. the ng-options will make the restrictions for me?

Comment: If you prefer receiving the whole object instead of just the id in `ng-model` (judging from your `ng-model` name), you can try taking away `e.EmpresaId as` as well.

Comment: I just have to Show the empresa.name for the user , and give to the ng-model="colaborador.empresa" , the empresa.IdEmpresa.

Comment: The empresa hava many colaborador , but colaborador have just one empresa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-repeat="empresa in empresas"` on the `<option>` tags.

Here's an example:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="empresa in empresas" value="{{empresa.EmpresaId}}">{{empresa.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**Controller Code**

```
$scope.empresas = [
  { EmpresaId: 101, name: 'India' },
  { EmpresaId: 102, name: 'US' },
  { EmpresaId: 103, name: 'UK' }
];
```

Comment: <option ng-repeat="empresa in empresas"  value="{{empresa.EmpresaId}}">{{empresa.name}}</option>
 </select>   like that?

Comment: Add a <select> in the beginning as well.